# Using Javascript to display an ad based on Text on a page

Tags: javascript, text

I know what I want to do should be done with a database, but my programmers are backed up and I want to use some test code to test a concept.

I want to put up 1 of 5 unique ads on a page. The type of ad will be based on a piece of text located on the page.

For example I have 1000 pages showing homes for sale. If that home is in XYZ county, then I want to show an ad  called XYZ.jpg.  However if that home is in ABC County, then I want to show an ad called ABC.jpg

So can javascript scan a page and if a word is found, display certain text? Or if not scan a page, at least scan the "County" field.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some relevant HTML?

Comment: Yes you can do this, but some code would be nice.  the best way is to give this hidden (or otherwise) field an id; and on page load find it, post for the appropriate images, and update a container with the relevant paths/info.

Comment: Lets use this URL as an example http://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-detail/1203-Musket-Ct-Ne_Leesburg_VA_20176_M60059-33379?source=web And this home is in Loudoun. I want all homes like this, that are in Loudoun to display the text "Hello World Loudoun". And then if the house is in Fairfax, I want the text to display "Fairfax Rocks" and if neither, write nothing.  Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.innerText.indexOf('keyword') != -1) {
    document.getElementById('ad_div').innerText = "Found " + keyword + "!";
}
```

Comment: realistically, though, this is not practical.  If the keyword is in some unrelated paragraph, it will show it; and worse, if you have "haven" and "new haven" counties, you'll get conflicting results.  Setting up an element with an id is going to be cleaner and more reliable.

Comment: What if I know the counties? The test will be on two counties. Like if LOUDOUN (a county) is on the site show html A. If Fairfax is on the site, show html B. If neither, show nothing.  Hey my brother's name is MARC and his last name starts with B, I wonder if he is a programmer too!

Comment: On the link you posted above, the county is prefixed by 'County: ', so Marc's answer should work for you. Just change 'keyword' to 'County: Loudon' or 'County: Fairfax'. Although I wouldn't consider it to be very efficient, as you're going to be pulling all the text from the DOM and searching it.